# Which TypeScript transpiling flow is for what case?

Tags: typescript

I am looking at how TypeScript may be used in projects and I see multiple ways for doing this:

1. Babel with [TypeScript preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript) + WebPack
2. TypeScript compiler with + Babel for generated JS + WebPack
3. WebPack + [TypeScript loader](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/)

However, I am not super experienced front-end developer, so could anyone compare these options and provide pros and cons of each?

Thanks.